# $X_t$ is a cadlag semimartingale implies $f(X_t)$ is a semimartingale by using Ito's Lemma

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

In [this](https://almostsure.wordpress.com/2010/01/25/the-generalized-ito-formula/) post from George Lowther's blog (shortly after equation (6)), he claims that, for a cadlag semi martingale $X_t$, $f(X_t)$ is a semi-martingale because $f(t)$ obeys the generalized Ito formula $$f(X_t)=f(X_0)+\int_{0+}^tf'(X_{s-})dX_s+\frac{1}{2}\int_{0+}^tf''(X_{s-})d[X]_t+\sum_{t \leq T}(\Delta f(X_t)-f'(X_{t-})\Delta X_t-\frac{1}{2}f''(X_{t-})(\Delta X_t)^2). $$

**Question:**

Now I don't understand how the claim follows from the expression of the Ito formula. Clearly, the stochastic integrals and the integration wrt to the quadratic variation are semi martingales and the term $f'(X_{t-})\Delta X_t$ can be seen as $\int_{0+}^tf'(X_{t-})dX_t-\int_{0+}^{t-}f'(X_{t-})dX_t$ and similarly for the $\frac{1}{2}f''(x_{t-})(\Delta X_t)^2$. Since the space of semimartingales is a vector space, the countable sum of these terms are again semi-martingale.(using the fact that the jumps are countable for a caglad process). What I dont understand is how can I see that $\Delta f(X_t)$ is a semi-martingale? Can it be rewritten as some stochastic integral or some tricks like that?

Comment: $\Delta f(X_t)$ is a finite variation process (because it a a.s. finite pure jump process) hence a semimartingale, or am I missing something ?

Comment: @TheBridge But the sum could be countably infinite isnt it?

Comment: Ok reading the proof the thing is like this the entire term $$\sum_{t \leq T}(\Delta f(X_t)-f'(X_{t-})\Delta X_t-\frac{1}{2}f''(X_{t-})(\Delta X_t)^2)$$ is almsot surely finite from the argument.of the blog. So this process is a semimartingale. As it decomposes as the difference of the term you are interested in and 2 semimartingales (those two being semimartingales is clear for you from your post) then as semimaringale space is a vector space it has to be a semimartingale.

Comment: @TheBridge Right, because it is bounded by the quadratic variation which is finite. Many thanks.

Comment: You are welcome but (almost) everything was in the blog, so I did nothing really.